# How can I define which element jquery should use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a gallery so I got this while and every image has a different ID but when clicking the image I did a function to open it and add some css, like a popup with some css, the problem is that those jquery functions works with the ID of the image but every image has a differente ID. How can I do to make it work?

```js
popup = {
  init: function() {
    $('figure').click(function() {
      popup.open($(this));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.popup img', function() {
      return false;
    }).on('click', '.popup', function() {
      popup.close();
    })
  },
  open: function($figure) {
    $('#imagenabierta').css('clip-path', 'none');
    $('#imagenabierta').css('height', '500px');
    $('#imagenabierta').css('width', '800px');
    $('.gallery').addClass('pop');
    $popup = $('<div class="popup" />').appendTo($('body'));
    $fig = $figure.clone().appendTo($('.popup'));
    $bg = $('<div class="bg" />').appendTo($('.popup'));
    $close = $('<div class="close"><svg><use xlink:href="#close"></use></svg></div>').appendTo($fig);
    $shadow = $('<div class="shadow" />').appendTo($fig);
    src = $('img', $fig).attr('src');
    $shadow.css({
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')'
    });
    $bg.css({
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')'
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.popup').addClass('pop');
    }, 10);
  },
  close: function() {
    $('#imagenabierta').css('clip-path', 'polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%)');
    $('#imagenabierta').css('height', '305px');
    $('#imagenabierta').css('width', '382px');
    $('.gallery, .popup').removeClass('pop');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.popup').remove()
    }, 100);
  }
}

popup.init()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="grid--item">
          <figure>
            <img class="img" src="..." alt="Imagen" height="500px" width="800px" id="imagenabierta1">
            <figcaption>comentario 1<small>$fecha1</small></figcaption>
            <div class="container">
              <h2>$titulo1</h2>
              <div class="desc">$creador 1</div>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="grid--item">
          <figure>
            <img class="img" src="..." alt="Imagen" height="500px" width="800px" id="imagenabierta2">
            <figcaption>comentario 2<small>$fecha2</small></figcaption>
            <div class="container">
              <h2>$titulo2</h2>
              <div class="desc">$creador 2</div>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="grid--item">
          <figure>
            <img class="img" src="..." alt="Imagen" height="500px" width="800px" id="imagenabierta3">
            <figcaption>comentario 3<small>$fecha3</small></figcaption>
            <div class="container">
              <h2>$titulo3</h2>
              <div class="desc">$creador 3</div>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: use a common class to trigger the function. It will apply to all the images. Then inside the function refer to 'this' to refer to that specific image between all that share the same class

Comment: This is NOT a PHP question. I clicked edit, then the button with the `[<>]` snippet editor. Then I changed your PHP to PLAIN HTML and JavaScript in a [mcve] - you can get images from placeholder.com. Please add CSS and Images yourself

Comment: Your ID is invalid anyway, there cannot be spaces in an ID - change `$('#imagenabierta')`  to `$('.imagenabierta')` and use a class instead of ID

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thank you for answering. Do you mean something like

`open: function($figure) {`
    `$(this).css('clip-path','none');`

this?

Comment: Solved, thank you to everyone